# Set encoding for a nodeJS Transform stream in a safe manner

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, encoding, utf-8

According to nodeJS [docs(v5.10.0)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) for a Readable stream:

> it is better to use `readable.setEncoding('utf8')` than working with
>   buffers directly using `buf.toString(encoding)`. This is because
>   "multi-byte characters (...) would otherwise be potentially mangled.
>   If you want to read the data as strings, always use this method.

My question is about how to implement this using the new API for Transform streams. There is no need now to go through the inheritance verbose method.

So, for example this would work as a way to transform stdin into an upper case string

```
const transform = require("stream").Transform({
  transform: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    this.push(chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
    next();
  }
});

process.stdin.pipe(transform).pipe(process.stdout);
```

However, this would appear to go against the recommendation of not using `toString()` on buffers. I've tried modifying the Transform instance by setting encoding to "utf-8" like this:

```
const transform = require("stream").Transform({
  transform: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    this.push(chunk.toUpperCase()); //chunk is a buffer so this doesn't work
    next();
  }
});
transform.setEncoding("utf-8");

process.stdin.pipe(transform).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Upon inspection, `transform` in the first case has an encoding of null, whereas in the second it has indeed changed to "utf-8". Yet, the chunk passed to the transform function is still a buffer. I thought that by setting encoding `toString()` method could be skipped but this is not the case.

I've also tried extending the `read` method as in the Readable and Duplex examples, but that is not allowed.

Is there a way to get rid of `toString()`?

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Using `Buffer#toString` directly in your _transform method is bad. However, setEncoding is meant to be used by readable stream *consumers* (i.e. the code that reads from your transform stream). You are *implementing* a transform stream. It doesn't change the input of your _transform method for you.

Internally, readable streams use the [StringDecoder](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/string_decoder.html) if the consumer activated auto-decoding. You can use it in your transform method as well.

Here's a [code comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/85ab4a5f1281c4e1dd06450ac7bd3250326267fa/lib/string_decoder.js#L55) explaining how it works:

> [StringDecoder] decodes the given buffer and returns it as JS string that is guaranteed to not contain any partial multi-byte characters. Any partial character found at the end of the buffer is buffered up, and will be returned when calling write again with the remaining bytes.

So, your example could be rewritten as follows:

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder
const transform = require("stream").Transform({
  transform: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    if(!this.myStringDecoder) this.myStringDecoder = new StringDecoder('utf8')
    this.push(this.myStringDecoder.write().toUpperCase());
    next();
  }
});

process.stdin.pipe(transform).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: My first snippet works as is, so there wouldn't be the need to use StringDecoder directly. I'm just puzzled the docs say that Transform instances "implement both the Readable and Writable interfaces," when for what you're saying it doesn't seem to be the case. StringDecoder does exactly the opposite of what is recommended for Readable

Comment: Your snippet works as long as no multibyte chars are separated into different chunks. I recommend using string decoder for transform streams that work on text. The docs are a bit ambiguos. They merely state 'Call this function to cause the stream to return' unmingled strings, but as this is the *consumer's* section I think it's clear that this has no effect on implementors. What do you think of that StringDecoder does that is not recommended?

Comment: If you also control the consuming end of your transform stream, then you could call `setEncoding` on `process.stdin`.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to setEncoding just for the consumer side? I tried setting this in my second example before streaming stdin but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, so it's not a bug in node. Piping causes the strings that stdin outputs after setting the encoding to be turned into buffers again, but they *are* run through StringDecoder.

Comment: We may be getting there but still my question is how to avoid StringDecoder behaviour as that goes against what the docs recommends

Comment: What do you mean by "how to avoid StringDecoder behaviour"? You don't want to have to use StringDecoder manually? --> you don't need to if you setEncoding on the input stream. You don't want to have to use toString()? --> you can get around that by turning off the decodeStrings strings option in your transform stream

Answer (score 2):

Pass '**decodeStrings: false**' as '**options**' property to Transform's *constructor*:

```js
const transform = require("stream").Transform({
    transform: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
        this.push(chunk.toUpperCase()); //chunk is a buffer so this doesn't work
        next();
    },
    decodeStrings: false
});
```